# jemalloc / jeprof shows addresses not function names based on lg_prof_interval

Tags: memory-leaks, profiling, jemalloc

I'm trying to debug a memory leak in some vendor-provided JNI/native code and, like many people it seems, started here:
https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2015/12/11/using-jemalloc-to-get-to-the-bottom-of-a-memory-leak/

I've found if I run:

```
export MALLOC_CONF=prof:true,lg_prof_interval:30,lg_prof_sample:17
```

then run my application, and then run the `jeprof ...` command to generate the .gif I can see the JNI function names causing the leak (which is good!).

I tried changing `lg_prof_interval:30` to `lg_prof_interval:25` which produces .heap files much more frequently, but I've found the JNI function names I mentioned previously have been replaced by addresses (0x000123...). I haven't made any other changes, and have double- and triple- checked that running with `lg_prof_interval:30` lets me see the function names in the resulting .gifs, but `lg_prof_interval:25` doesn't.

The reason I want to use `lg_prof_interval:25` is because I need to re-run the profiling with a slimmed-down version of the application suffering the memory leaks, but I fear it will take forever to use 2^30 bytes so will never see a .heap file.

I've seen similar questions where the answers have suggested installing a dbg version of the jdk, yet I struggle to see why this could be the cause in my case.

Many thanks in advance.

TLDR: can see function names with `lg_prof_interval:30` but not `lg_prof_interval:25`

Comment: My guess is that with :30 the program has been alive long enough for the method names to have been 'cached' somewhere, but not with :25 which starts dumping .heap files almost straight away, but that is purely speculation.

Comment: How are you invoking jeprof?

Comment: jeprof --show_bytes --gif /path/to/jvm/bin/java jeprof*.heap > /tmp/app-profiling.gif

Comment: This happened to me today. It turns out that doing `jeprof*.heap` is a bad idea: it will include all profiles by ALL applications that happen to use jemalloc. In my case, I noticed files that look like `jeprof.43312.xxxx.heap` where as the PID of the application was different. So it was mixing everything up. The right way to run this command is using `jeprof.PID_OF_THE_APP.*.heap`